# How do I count the number of marked elements in a CheckedListBox

Tags: c#

There is an "checkedlistbox" (chDay), I'm trying to find out the number of marked points, "Selected" is emphasized to me.

```
                    int count = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < chDay.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (chDay.Items[i].Selected == true)
                        {
                            count = count + 1;
                        }
                    }
```

Type of error:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want [`GetItemChecked()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked?view=windowsdesktop-8.0)??

Comment: You could also do `chDay.CheckedItems.Count` IF all you want is the count.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how many items have been marked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CheckedListBox` has a property called [`CheckedItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems?view=windowsdesktop-8.0) that represents the checked items as a collection, so the simplest method if you want the count is:

```
var count = chDay.CheckedItems.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < chDay.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (chDay.GetItemChecked(i))
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```